# Build folder ./build does not exist

Tags: python, django

[image]

I was trying to deploy my *django* project using *render* and I am getting this error that build does not exists.. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help?

I tried to look for  any solutions on the internet but could not find any...I don't know if I typed any code wrong or am I missing some commands.

Comment: What did you type earlier?. What commands were executed?

Answer (score 0):

In settings section make sure build command is "npm run build" and not "npm build"